# Menu elements active state

Tags: php, css, menu

So i have been working on this problem all day, and i do not seem to becomming across a solution for this. I have googled the internet dry, however i have not been able to come a cross any help which i could use.

I know that there are many similar questions out there, but again none of which have helped me, even though it seems to be a simple problem.

My problem is the active state of the menu element on this page: http://dev.ateo.dk/om-ateo/

Its the "Om Ateo" and the "Ofte stillede spørgsmål" which will not become active elements in the menu, even though it is active.

I have set the body class and the body id to match the id's of the li element, but none of this seems to work in any way.

Comment: Are you asking how you can change the CSS of a specific `li` in that menu depending on what page you are on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply some CSS on the class current-menu-item.

```
.current-menu-item {
    font-weight:bold;
    /* or anything else that you want*/
}
```